# Translate PHP mcrypt_decrypt function to Lua

Tags: php, encryption, lua, mcrypt, php-openssl

I need to translate next PHP code to Lua:

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $message, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

to Nginx+Lua.

I have openssl extension, but the problem is MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256. I do not know what method for openssl I need to use, and as I understood from this post: http://thefsb.tumblr.com/post/111035508040/porting-php-code-from-mcrypt-to-openssl I can't use openssl at all. Any other solutions?

Also, you may say I should not use mcrypt_decrypt/encrypt or MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 at all, but I must, since I need to port PHP project to Nginx+Lua and changing encryption method will break whole system at the moment and consequences will be devastating.

Comment: Have you tried any of the lua mcrypt libraries?

Comment: Omg, I haven't even tried to search for that. I thought mcrypt is only for php.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003.

Comment: You should definitely try and move away from mcrypt and definitely ECB and Rijndael-256 (which is not actually AES due to the block size). ECB is insecure. If somebody is able to get too much information from ECB or other cryptographic mistakes the consequences can be equally devastating.